# JSTL nested foreach loop not printing

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Currently working on a project where I receive an ArrayList of Map objects from a Servlet in a JSP.  The way it works is when the page is pulled up there is a AJAX call via jquery to a Servlet that will send a response back with the necessary List of Maps.  The issue that I am having is after the page is loaded I am trying to build a table based on the values in the Map objects.  The code I have appears to be working (somewhat).  When I view the XHR response with firebug I can see that the proper tags are there throughout the page where expected(ie. the tr and td tags).  When I try and view the page in the browser and with "View Source" however the HTML that would be created inside the forEach loops are not there only the HTML i created manually is.

```
    <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Home</th>
                <th>Away</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="currentTeam" items="${GamesList}">
                <tr id="game">
                <c:forEach var="currentGame" items="${currentTeam}">
                    <c:if test="${currentGame.key eq 'Home' }">
                        <td>${currentGame.value}</td>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${currentGame.key eq 'Visitor' }">
                        <td>${currentGame.value }</td>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
```

Is the current code that I am using. Which is itself enclosed in a div tag.  Not sure if it helps but this div is only going to be displayed when a user clicks a button to open a Jquery pop-up window.  Any help would be appreciated.

The XHR response viewed in Firebug looks like this

```
              <tr><td>New York Giants</td><td>Dallas Cowboys</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Chicago Bears</td><td>Indianapolis Colts</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Minneosta Vikings</td><td>Jacksonville Jaguars</td></tr>
                <tr><td>New York Jets</td><td>Buffalo Bills</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Houston Texans</td><td>Miami Dolphins</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Tennessee Titans</td><td>New England Patriots</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Detroit Lions</td><td>St. Louis Rams</td></tr>
                <tr><td>New Orleans Saints</td><td>Washington Redskins</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Cleveland Browns</td><td>Philadelphia Eagles</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Kansas City Chiefs</td><td>Atlanta Falcons</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Green Bay Packers</td><td>San Francisco 49ers</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Arizona Cardinals</td><td>Seattle Seahawks</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</td><td>Carolina Panthers</td></tr>
```

Cut for brevity. While the View Source looks as follows:

```
                <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Home</th>
                <th>Away</th>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Is there current code are you using?

Comment: what's the output ? what's the value of `currentGame.value` ?

Comment: The current code that I am using is listed Above. currentGame.value prints out to the proper team names ONLY in the XHR response viewed in firebug.  When I look anywhere else (View Source) there is no output.

Comment: Is `GamesList` present before the ajax call?

Comment: Could you show the ajax call?

Comment: `$.ajax({
  url:"/PlanetSports/ProcessingServlet",
  data:"weekInfo=true",
  type:"POST"});` Is the ajax call.  It is just a quick boolean value to tell the Servlet what to process.  GameList is passed back to the JSP page with the following code `request.setAttribute("GamesList", currentWeekGames);
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response);`

Comment: Cna you print it using a scriptlet to see if the data is really being pumped in ? I don't see any problems with looping

Comment: Ok so it appears that I cannot even access the data with a scriptlet.. which brings up the question of "why?" since, as I said, when I look at the data coming IN via Firebug's "Net" feature I can see all of the data properly formatted and there as expected on the XHR Response.

Comment: Here is the stack trace of what I'm getting. Figured it would be helpful. `Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:567)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:471)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)`

Comment: Never mind the NullPointer.  Figured out that the value is only null during the initial pageload. After the Ajax call fires the data is returned as expected.  I tried running a simple test in scriptlets for it to just print the word "Test" in the table and got no where... Its just not printing.  Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm using Tomcat 7 instead of 6?

Comment: Do you have a full stacktrace? From which file is the first code section and which view is served from `/PlanetSports/ProcessingServlet`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out the issue. It was with the way that I was passing data using the fowrard() method instead of response.getWriter().write().  Once I changed to that and changed the data being returned from a hashmap to a JSONObject I was able to read everything properly.

Comment: @djdgel For other users having similar problems, you could post the solution as an answer (and accept it) if you like

Answer (score 0):

print the list in Servlet and set result to a div content as follows

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "\ServletCall", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});

<table>
            <tr>
                <th>Home</th>
                <th>Away</th>
            </tr>
<div id="div1"></div>
</table>
```